# 1st 'equations of mathematical physics' book for self study

Tags: reference-request, heat-equation, wave-equation

I've already covered some differential equations (1st/2nd order, Cauchy/Euler's equation, Chebyshev's equation, Frobenius method, system of differential equations, Sturm Liouville problems) and basic Hilbert space theory (orthogonal projection, orthonormal systems, generalized Fourier series) Laplace and Fourier transforms . now i am trying to learn how to solve the 3 famous equations of mathematical physics : the heat, wave and Laplace equations in 1 and 2 dimensions with different types of initial/boundary condition.

I've checked some PDE books but they're too vast and for now since I don't have much free time I prefer to limit myself to those particular equations.

is there some books that focus mainly on those 3 equations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Farlow?  PRetty user friendly.

IF that is still too long, take a look at Kreyszig Engineering Mathematics.  (I am familiar with the 5th edition, but they are all probably similar).  Only a single chapter on PDEs and just covers the high spots with emphasis on the big 3.  Might fit you well.